# SSIS error with Oracle - Exception deserialzing the package "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: oracle, ssis, oracle12c, sql-server-2016, ole

I am taking an existing SQL Server 2016 SSIS package and trying to add an Execute SQL Task.  I'm suspicious that the task itself isn't the problem, but just in case, I'll explain it.

It is a simple task to query the count in a table, using an existing OLE connection.  I create a user variable, set the ResultSet to Single Row, and put in my statement: "SELECT COUNT(fld) FROM MY_TABLE"  It shows no errors, but when I try to execute it, I get the error in the title.  I can change it to a BEGIN SELECT COUNT(fld) FROM MY_TABLE; END; or add a GO on the 2nd line - it makes no difference.  I can set the ResultSet to None, and it makes no difference.  I can create a new OLE Connection and use that, and it makes no difference.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the Oracle driver, because nothing in the paragraph above makes any sense.  I can test the connection and it works, however, and when I use the existing connection, it is parameterized for the project.

So what next?  Reinstall the Oracle drivers?  Or is there anything less drastic?

I started a new project, make a new OLE connection, a new Execute SQL task, and call an Oracle procedure.  It works just fine.  It's just trying to edit an existing project that doesn't work.  Sometimes.

Oh, I'm also using Visual Studio 2019.